# Binding a gridview via a dynamic DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, datatable

I have a `GridView` and I need to bind it with a dynamic Data Table.

I have a `List<List<string>>` and a `List<List<DateTime>>`.

I need a DataTable with 3 columns, namely `FileName`, `LastAccessTimeForServer1`, `LastAccessTimeForServer2`.

The `List<List<string>>` would contain 2 lists of filenames(common for both the servers), while `List<List<DateTime>>` would contain 2 lists of last access times (different for both the files).

Below is the code which I have tried, which doesn't make much sense to me.

Completely perplexed.

```
string serviceName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
List<string> serviceNameArray = new List<string>();
for (int x = 1; x <= 2; x++)
{
if (x < 2)
{
serviceNameArray.Add(@"\\Server10" + x + @"\WebSite" + "\\" + serviceName);
}
else
{
serviceNameArray.Add(@"\\Server1" + x + @"\WebSite" + "\\" + serviceName);
}
}
List<List<string>> ultimateList = new List<List<string>>();
List<int> numList = new List<int>();
//Call the Search method

for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
{
ultimateList.Add(Search(serviceNameArray[y]));
}
for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
{
numList.Add(ultimateList[z].Count);
}

//FInd the Last Write Time for all the files.
for (int xx = 0; xx < 2; xx++)
{
listOfDateTimes.Add(new List<DateTime>());
for (int yy = 0; yy < numList[xx]; yy++)
{
listOfDateTimes[xx].Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(ultimateList[xx][yy]));
}
}
    DataTable dtForGridView = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("LastAccessTimeForServer1", typeof(DateTime));
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("LastAccessTimeForServer2", typeof(DateTime));
    dtForGridView.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dtForGridView.Columns.Add(dc2);
    dtForGridView.Columns.Add(dc3);

    for (int k = 0; k <=2; k++)
    {
    for (int d = 0; d < numList[k]; d++)//numList[k] will give the number of rows in each column
    {
    dtForGridView.Rows.Add(ultimateList[d][k], listOfDateTimes[k]);
    }
    }
    //Binding the GridView
    GridView1.DataSource = dtForGridView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

The final grid should look like:

```
FileName    LastAccessTimeForServer1          LastAccessTimeForServer1
a.txt        Time1                             Time2
b.txt        Time3                             Time4
```

Experts please help in finding a solution. 
Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Anurag

Comment: You have two columns `LastAccessTimeForServer1`. You also have `<=2` instead of `<2` which doesn't work if you have only two lists.

Comment: @TimSchmelter..Thats a typo. Second would be LastAccessTimeForServer2. I will edit it just now.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Edited the post to insert the whole code.